# Git : how to push some commits on another branch

Tags: git

This is my git :

```
               x--x--v2--x--x--x - dev
              /
x--x--x--x--v1 - prod
```

I would like now to push all commits until v2 from dev branch to prod branch, but v2 is not my last commit on dev branch.
How can i do? (I do'nt have any tags, v1 v2 are actually just classic commits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can push any commit-ish, just specify it in an explicit refspec like

```
git push origin v2:prod
```

Or you can also do

```
git checkout -B prod v2
git push origin prod
```